# How to make div expand all the way to the right

Tags: xhtml, html, css

The demo page: [**CLICK HERE**](http://meyers.ipalaces.org/WIP_BRIAN/)

I have made a picture to show:
[image]

As clearly seen in the picture, there is a gap from the div `left_bg` and the div `middle_bg`. The `left_bg` has no content, and its width should be fluid and fit inside it's div container `top-container`. Just to help demonstrate the gap  I have it set `left_bg` to `width:500px`. However, Please note that the width should be fluid. The div `middle_bg` will also be fluid, as it will allow for different text longer or shorter.

How can I get rid of this gap and allow `left_bg` to fit?

**Update**

I am thinking that perhaps using CSS like a table would accomplish what I am after. I tried tweaking and messing around but I could not quite get it to work. I have set `100 rep bounty` to assist me with this problem.

Comment: actually you have a much more tricky issue there with the background behind the rounded corners

Comment: @Sam thats the next question :)

Comment: I think that you're maybe making this more difficult for yourself than need be, *three* divs for background purposes?

Comment: @ricebowl The reason I went that route is because the tab where it states michicraft Boats is actually transparent. I welcome any alterntive and simpler methods than 3 DIVs though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tables would be the best way of doing this

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="top">
            <td style="width: 100%; height: 85px;">
                <div class="left_bg">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="">
                <div class="middle_bg">
                    <p>
                        Michicraft Boats</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="right_bg">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="top-container-links">
                    <a href="#">Find Nearest Dealer</a> | &nbsp;<a href="#">Request a Quote</a></div>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and change your css to

```
#top-container .left_bg
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #A3AFC6;
        border-color: white -moz-use-text-color white white;
        border-style: solid none solid solid;
        border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
        height: 85px;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
        border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
        behavior: url(/PIE/PIE.htc);
    }
    #top-container .middle_bg
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #A3AFC6;
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        float: right;
        height: 44px;
        margin-top: -42px;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: The width needs to be fluid. 514px works when `middle-bg` is Michicraft Boats. But when I make the text "test" the width then needs to be more than 514px...thus its not fluid.

Comment: have edited my answer, i have used tables which according to me is the easiest way of acheiving this

Comment: This works. I can even using CSS `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to mimic this functionality. Of course, it doesnt work for IE6 and IE7. I really dont like the extra markup of using a table but it seems the only option. I am giving this question another day before I accept the fact I have to use old fashion tables and accept your answer

Comment: I need the bounty for something else. I've decided to accept this answer. I am tired of doing different things for IE6, IE7, and IE8. I am deciding on just using conditional CSS statments for css for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
#top-container .middle_bg {
    width: 263px;
}
```

Since `#top-container` is 775px, `.left_bg` is 500 with a left margin of 1 and `.righ_bg` is 10px with a right margin of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Got it stick to right by setting width of `#top-container .left_bg` to **514px**.

Edit :

change `#top-container .middle_bg p` to absolute positioning :

```
position:absolute;
right:2px;
bottom:0px;
```

and add into `#top-container`

```
position:relative;
```

also keep `#top-container .left_bg` width to **514px**.

Answer (score 0):

if you set its width to 514px it touches the blue. if you want it to go all the way to the right then change #top-container .left_bg

to

position:absolute;
width:773px;

Comment: I want it so it touches the blue, but not hard-code the width in. I want it to allow the middle-bg to be fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is done by seeting the div to `width: 100%` and the element itself and the elements right of it floating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating the layout of that navigation area.  I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
        background-color: #949dad;
        padding: 0;
      } 
      p {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
      }
      .brand {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-color: #949DAD;
        -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
        border:1px solid white;
        border-bottom-style: none;
        font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
        font-size:31px;
        margin:44px 0 0 0;
        min-width:215px;
        padding:5px 10px 0;
        position:relative;
        float: right;
        height: 36px;
        overflow: visible;
      }

      .brand_container {
        font-size:12px;
        background-color:#A3AFC6;
        border: 1px solid white;
        height:85px;
        text-align:center;
        -moz-border-radius:20px 0 0 20px;
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #A3AFC6;
        float:left;
        width:800px;
        padding:0px 5px;
        margin:0 0 20px 0;
      }

      .brand .links {
        width:100%;
        float:right;
        clear:both;
        margin-top:1px;
        font-size:11px; 
        font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        text-align:center; 
      }
      .brand .links a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
      .brand .links a:hover{color:#fff; text-decoration:underline;}

      .body {
        margin-top: 105px;
        width:800px;
        padding:0px 5px;
        border: 1px solid white; 
        clear: both;
        background-color:#A3AFC6;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="brand_container">
      <div class="brand">
        <p>Michicraft Boats</p>
        <div class="links"><a href="#">Find Nearest Dealer</a> | &nbsp;<a href="#">Request a Quote</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body"> Content here <br><br><br><br></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This indeed a simpler approach if I didn't need the `brand` class to be transparent. Unless there is a way to force a "cutout" effect in CSS, I can't have the `brand-container` underneath the `brand`

Comment: @BHare, yeah, I saw from another of your questions that you are going to put an image behind all that.  In that case you will need a complicated layout.  There might be a way to simulate the cutout without needing so many divs, however.